# Java JNI with C function using gsl.

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, gsl

I am trying to use JNI in order to call a function defined in c. It is really weird because when I run my java program, sometimes I get one mistake and other times I get a different one. Here they are:

```
     82 [main] java (5556) C:\Windows\system32\java.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x612708F0/0x17FF08F0.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\cygwin\home\Juli▒n\Pruebas_JNI\Caracterizacion.dll: Se realiz▒ un acceso no v▒lido a la ubicaci▒n de memoria
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:6)
Exception in thread "main"
```

and

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Main.caracterizar()[F
        at Main.caracterizar(Native Method)
        at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I think I have done everything right, even thought it seems I haven't.

Here is my C function

```
/* 
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: OCARDONAM
 * Created on 14 de enero de 2013, 11:46 AM
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
#include "sizedata.h"
#include "elementary_math_vec.h"
#include "contar.h"
#include "media.h"
#include "Main.h"


JNIEXPORT jfloatArray JNICALL Java_Main_caracterizar (JNIEnv *env, jclass class) {
    //variables
    int n_fil, n1, n2, i;
    char *filename;
    //features names
    double m,T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,T11;//,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10,F11;
    //load signal and define its size
    filename = "reg_test.txt";
    tamano(filename, &n1, &n2);
    n_fil = n1-2;

    gsl_vector * v = gsl_vector_alloc (n_fil); 
    {
        FILE * f = fopen (filename, "r");
        gsl_vector_fscanf (f, v);
        fclose (f);
    }


    // statistics features in time domain
    double data[n_fil],tmp[n_fil];
    for (i = 0; i < n_fil; i++)
    {
        data[i] = gsl_vector_get(v,i);
    }

    //centered data
    m = gsl_stats_mean(data, 1, n_fil);
    for (i = 0; i < n_fil; i++) {
        data[i] = data[i]-m;
        gsl_vector_set(v,i,data[i]);
    }
    T1 = gsl_stats_mean(data, 1, n_fil);  //mean
    T2 = gsl_stats_sd_m(data, 1, n_fil, T1); //standard deviation    
    T3 = gsl_blas_dnrm2(v)/sqrt(n_fil);//RMS
    T4 = gsl_stats_skew(data, 1, n_fil); //skewness    
    T5 = gsl_stats_kurtosis(data, 1, n_fil) + 3; //kurtosis
    T6 = ch_T6(data,n_fil);
    T7 = ch_T7(data,n_fil); //absolute maximum
    T8 = T7/T3; //Crest Factor
    T9 = T7/T6;
    T10 = ch_T10(data,n_fil,T3);//Shape Factor
    T11 = ch_T11(data,n_fil,T7);


    //print a vector 

    jfloat res[1000];
    jfloatArray jres;

    for (i = 0; i < n1-2; i++) {
        res[i] = (jfloat) gsl_vector_get(v, i);
    }
    gsl_vector_free (v); 

    (*env)->SetFloatArrayRegion(env, jres, 0, n1-2, res);
    return jres;
}
```

and here is the java code I use to invoke it:

```
public class Main {

    public native float[] caracterizar();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("Caracterizacion");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        float ans[] = (new Main()).caracterizar();

        for (int i=0 ; i<ans.length ; i++)
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, here is what I've used to compile and link the c program:

```
gcc -D__int64="long long" -c -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_11/include/ -I/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_11/include/win32/ -o Main.o Main.c
```

Link:

```
gcc -shared -L/usr/local/lib -o Caracterizacion.dll Main.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

I am not sure where the mistake is. I've tested other JNI programs and they work fine, so I think the problem is the way I'm including the gsl library.

I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running this on Linux ?

Comment: No. I haven't. You think that might be the problem?

Comment: From the error, it looks like it's an environment error and not coding error, I suggest you test it on different environment such as Linux, where gcc is native to the system...

Answer (score 3):

Do not use cygwin GCC, unless you really want to have your program linked to cygwin libraries. If you need it, you have to package cygwin dlls into your package as well.

If you want it running on Windows, use mingw compiler (there is package also for Cygwin, but it will create cygwin independent binary.) or MSVC project. Unless Java is cygwin enabled, it will not understand cygwin paths, but your native code will. That will become really confusing. Unless you know you need it, use cygwin for scripting, but use mingw-gcc as compiler to make binaries or use Min Lin's studio project.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your gsl library may be compiled and linked to a different version of cygwin. And your main.c code is compiled with your current version of cygwin, there is a conflict. You can try these:

1. rebuild your gsl using the current cygwin environment.
2. link to static libraries of gsl.
3. Use the msvc, gsl can be compiled on msvc, I have the [visual studio solution](https://github.com/lin-min/GSL1.15-Win), you can either make static or dynamic library.